# How to bulk reset password of a Google App account?

Tags: python-2.7, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-admin-sdk

I have Admin access to a Google domain. I want to do bulk password reset of user account and also if possible make them change their password after first sign in. Currently im doing this using GAM. is there any way to do this using App script or python script?

i have generated random password and tried to reset the password but its not happening.. I dont know how to connect with Admin SDK.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with both Python (how GAM does it) or Apps Script. From my POV, unless you need to move this process into the cloud (Apps Script) you might as well use GAM to complete the task.

That being said, in both instances, you're going to want to use the [Directory API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/) (within the Admin SDK) as this has access to change passwords and set change password at next login to true. I recommend taking a look at [this Apps Script page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/admin-sdk-directory) making note of the additional steps needed to use the Admin SDK within Apps Script.